# SharePoint Add List Attachment Programmatically 404

Tags: 2007, powershell, custom-list, wss-3.0

I'm not having much luck with this...

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$lists_pxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri 'https://myserver/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL' -UseDefaultCredential

$list = $lists_pxy.GetList('Test Me')

$list_and_view = $lists_pxy.GetListAndView('Test Me', '')
$view_id = $list_and_view.childnodes.item(1).name

$xdoc = [xml] (@'
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" ViewName="{0}">
   <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
      <Field Name="Title">Test Title</Field>
   </Method>
</Batch>
'@ -f $view_id)

$result = $lists_pxy.UpdateListItems('Test Me', $xdoc.Batch)

$list_item_id = $result.SelectNodes('//@ows_ID') | select -exp '#text'
$bytes = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("D:\my.file")
$lists_pxy.AddAttachment($list.Name, $list_item_id, "my.file", $bytes)
```

Every time I call AddAttachment I get a 404 error...

```
Exception calling "AddAttachment" with "4" argument(s): "The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to use Fiddler to be able to see further details of the network traffic between the client and server. Hopefully you find the cause of the 404 error.
I tested your code and it works in my environment.

Comment: Oh thats good to know, thanks! What vetsion of SharePoint did you test?

Comment: I have currently no MOSS 2007 / WSS 3.0, so it was SP 2013.

Comment: Actually I've come to find out it actually does work. The issue was the file size. I couldn't use AddAttachment with any thing over 21MB. Got a 404 for anything bigger. However I'm able to use IE to upload much bigger attachments.

Answer (score 1):

To allow the web service to upload larger files try to increase the value of `maxRequestLength` (`system.web/httpRuntime`) as well as the value of `maxAllowedContentLength` (`system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits`)
See [this forum thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998927/how-do-i-upload-large-25mb-files-to-a-web-service).

Comment: I should of mentioned, I already increased the SharePoint defaults using info from this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bgeoffro/archive/2008/03/19/list-attachments-over-50mb-need-more-than-an-increase-in-maximum-upload-size.aspx (website maxRequestLength: 2097151, executionTimeout: 999999, maxAllowedContentLength: 4294967295)